# Unquote quosure outside quasiquotation context

Tags: r, dplyr, survey, quosure

I am defining a function to get the predicted values of a regression model with survey data for different subgroups(subpopulations). I use the svyglm function from the survey package.

My problem concerns handling the subset option in the svyglm function. As it uses non-standard evaluation, which I understand means it doesn't take the column names as a string. I tried just using the columns name without strings and enquoting (enquo) and unquoting it (!!). However both options do not work. I also played around with ensym() and expr() but did not get any results.

## Data & library

```r
library(dplyr)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

mtcars <- read.table("https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/rdataset/source/file/master/csv/datasets/mtcars.csv",
                     sep=",", header=TRUE)

mtcars_cplx <- mtcars %>% as_survey_design(id = cyl, weights = qsec)

carb <- c(1:8)
cyl <- c(4:8)
new_data <- expand.grid(carb, cyl)
colnames(new_data) <- c("carb", "cyl")
```

## With quousure

### Function and Input

```r
subpop_pred <- function(formula, data, subpop, new_data) {
  
  subpop_quo <- enquo(subpop)
  subpop_txt <- data$variables %>% select(!!subpop_quo) %>% colnames()
  
  for(i in min(data$variables[subpop_txt]):max(data$variables[subpop_txt])){
    reg <- svyglm(formula, data, subset=!!subpop_quo==i)
    pred <- predict(reg, newdata=new_data)
    
    if(exists("reg_end")==TRUE){
      pred <- cbind(new_data, pred, confint(pred))
      pred[subpop_txt] <- i
      reg_end <- rbind(reg_end, pred)
    } else {
      reg_end <- cbind(new_data, pred, confint(pred))
      reg_end[subpop_txt] <- i
    }
  }
}

subpop_pred(mpg ~ carb + cyl + carb*cyl, 
            data=mtcars_cplx, 
            new_data=new_data,
            subpop=gear)
```

### Output/Error

```
 Error: Base operators are not defined for quosures.
Do you need to unquote the quosure?

  # Bad:
  myquosure == rhs

  # Good:
  !!myquosure == rhs
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace 
8. stop(cnd) 
7. abort(paste_line("Base operators are not defined for quosures.", 
    "Do you need to unquote the quosure?", "", "  # Bad:", bad, 
    "", "  # Good:", good, )) 
6. Ops.quosure(subpop_quo, i) 
5. eval(subset, model.frame(design), parent.frame()) 
4. eval(subset, model.frame(design), parent.frame()) 
3. svyglm.survey.design(formula, data, subset = !!subpop_quo == 
    i) 
2. svyglm(formula, data, subset = !!subpop_quo == i) 
1. subpop_pred(mpg ~ carb + cyl + carb * cyl, data = mtcars_cplx, 
    new_data = new_data, subpop = gear)
```

## Without quosure

### Function and Input

```r
subpop_pred <- function(formula, data, subpop, new_data) {
  
  subpop_quo <- enquo(subpop)
  subpop_txt <- data$variables %>% select(!!subpop_quo) %>% colnames()
  
  for(i in min(data$variables[subpop_txt]):max(data$variables[subpop_txt])){
    reg <- svyglm(formula, data, subset=subpop==i)
    pred <- predict(reg, newdata=new_data)
    
    if(exists("reg_end")==TRUE){
      pred <- cbind(new_data, pred, confint(pred))
      pred[subpop_txt] <- i
      reg_end <- rbind(reg_end, pred)
    } else {
      reg_end <- cbind(new_data, pred, confint(pred))
      reg_end[subpop_txt] <- i
    }
  }
}

subpop_pred(mpg ~ carb + cyl + carb*cyl, data=mtcars_cplx, new_data=new_data, subpop=gear)
```

### Output

```r
Error in eval(subset, model.frame(design), parent.frame()) : 
  object 'gear' not found 
5. eval(subset, model.frame(design), parent.frame()) 
4. eval(subset, model.frame(design), parent.frame()) 
3. svyglm.survey.design(formula, data, subset = subpop == i) 
2. svyglm(formula, data, subset = subpop == i) 
1. subpop_pred(mpg ~ carb + cyl + carb * cyl, data = mtcars_cplx, 
    new_data = new_data, subpop = gear)
```

Do you have an idea how to get the function to work?

Comment: How about manually subsetting the dataset within the function and passing it to the `data` argument of `svyglm()` instead of using the `subset` argument?  You could use, e.g., `filter()` since it looks like you are already using **dplyr**.

Comment: It looks like the `subset` argument works like the `subset()` function, which can be a bear to work with in functions (for me, anyway :-D).  I could force things (practicing with `lm()`) using `subset = rlang::eval_tidy( expr( !!subpop_quo == i), data =  data)`.  As soon as I start going down the rabbit hole of `expr()` and friends I figure I'm doing something wrong. :-P  Filtering manually and passing that to the model function seems more straightforward to me (i.e., `dat = filter(data, !!subpop_quo == i)`).

Comment: Thanks, @aosmith this worked. I am always a bit hesitant to use filter() as I don't know if some information might be lost. For example in Stata it is necessary to use the specific survey commands to filter for subpopulations to get the right standard error. However I wil experiment with that. Unfortunately I cannot vote you up as I accidentaly removed my upvote for your comment.

Comment: Oh, interesting about Stata.  In R I've always used the `subset` argument interchangeably with `subset()`, but that might be different in `svyglm`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get things working with the `subset` argument by mixing `expr()` and `rlang::tidy_eval()`.

The model line in your function could then read:

```
reg <- svyglm(formula, data = data, 
       subset = rlang::eval_tidy( expr( !!subpop_quo == i), data =  data) )
```

I don't know robust this is, though, or if there is some more straightforward approach to tidyeval.  Working on this made me realize that the `subset()` function/argument are difficult to work with in functions. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way to do it since `svyby()` don't seem to support `svyglm()`. Here, `quo_squash()` is used to pass the expressions into `subset()`.
This can be extended to do the predictions.

```
gears = unique(mtcars$gear)
lapply(gears, function(x) {
  subset(mtcars_cplx, !!quo_squash(gear == x)) %>% 
    svyglm(mpg ~ carb + cyl + carb*cyl, design = .)
})
```